# web connector is not connecting when quickbooks close

Tags: quickbooks

1. I have two companies(qbc files)
2. first company is having password authentication for qbc file and second company won't have any password authentication.
3. I open both the files in quickbooks desktop app and closed the quickbooks
4. For me second company is authenticating fine from web connector and for first company it is not authenticating(both are working fine on quickbooks open).

from authentication my code is like this

for authentication i wrote like this

public string[] authenticate(string strUserName, string strPassword)
        {

```
            string[] authReturn = new string[2];
            string evLogTxt = "WebMethod: authenticate() has been called by QBWebconnector" + "\r\n\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "Parameters received:\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string strUserName = " + strUserName + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string strPassword = " + strPassword + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "\r\n";

                authReturn[0] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                authReturn[1] = @"G:\QB insalation files\qbw files\QBfilename.QBW";

            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "Return values: " + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string[] authReturn[0] = " + authReturn[0].ToString() + "\r\n";
            evLogTxt = evLogTxt + "string[] authReturn[1] = " + authReturn[1].ToString();

            return authReturn;


    }
```

can any one help me on this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Mind to share your code with us?

Comment: @Filnor i edited my question with my authentication code. for this if i am closing my qb and trying to access with web connector it is not getting authenticated.can you look into this once